# How to maintain development losing any user's data

Tags: database, testing, development-strategy

Need suggestion

I developed a system with WordPress where users can register and publish posts.

There are currently two versions.
One is for production and the other is for development & testing.

Here, suppose
The product project url is pro. abc .com
And the development & testing project url is beta . abc .com.

beta .abc .com is a staging version of pro. abc .com (I can directly push the project from beta .abc .com to pro. abc .com with help of Softaculous).

As pro .abc .com is a production version and the data from the user's end will be added continuously. I don't want to overlap the data or lose any data from pro .abc .com after pushing the dev version to the production project.

How do I maintain this process? Please someone suggest the good practice of it.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Good practices.

When you pushing staging version to production [environment](https://12factor.net/config), you do this though [revision control system](https://12factor.net/codebase) to update your files. When you need to update database structure, you use [database migrations](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/easy-database-migrations-in-php-using-phinx/).

This means you have 2 different web-sites, that uses two different databases, or, at least, each web-site use it's own table prefix.

Environment settings for WordPress are stored inside [wp-config.php](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/editing-wp-config-php/)
You need different `DB_NAME` or `$table_prefix`

Comment: Database migrations work for content you're adding by script, but in this case it's likely content that's added through the admin site - possibly separately on both systems. And there may end up being ID clashes to deal with too. I'm not sure database migrations will just work here.

Comment: @Rup Question is about one production environment, where users publish their posts. Developer should not add posts on his development version of database and point to his local record ids. Bad idea. In my answer I mean only database structure changes. I.e. add or delete a field. Then publish new code and updata databse structure on production, without adding new data to database. Your scenario when script adding content should work fine if you run it on dev, make sure it works fine, and then update production, where you run this script once again. I cannot imagine and ID clash in this case.